# How to Find list of movies acted by an actor?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I use the below code to get the cast of a particular movie (Top 2 for instance). How can I get a list of all movies acted by the actor/actress?
For instance, I choose the movie **Inception** (1375666), and the cast is **Leonardo DiCaprio**. So how can I get the list of all movies acted by Leonardo DiCaprio ??

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()

movie = ia.get_movie('1375666')
actor = movie['cast']
print "Cast: "
for i in actor[:2]:
    for j in ia.search_person(str(i))[:1]:
        print i, j.personID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Let's take `actor` from your example and get his full filmography:

```
>>> full_person = ia.get_person(actor[0].getID(), info=["filmography"])
>>> full_person.keys()
['name', u'producer', u'archive footage', u'self', u'writer', u'actor', u'soundtrack', 'in development', 'birth notes', u'thanks', 'akas', 'birth date', 'canonical name', 'long imdb name', 'long imdb canonical name']
>>> full_person["actor"]
[<Movie id:1663202[http] title: ...]
```

The last line gives you the list of movies where this person is an actor. But remember that in `ia.get_person(...)` you made an http request to imdb.com. And for list of actors it can take some time.